# QByteArray and its normal c++ equivalent

Tags: c++, qt

I have a previous code written in QT. The output generated is very slow. 
I have a very basic knowledge of QT. 
I wish to know the of `QByteArray` object and `QChar` to normal c++ equivalent.

The `Datapackage` class in Qt.

```
class Datapackage
{
public:
    Datapackage(QByteArray datas,int start);
    QVector<double> getX() const;
    QVector<double> getY() const;

private:
    QVector<QChar> intensity;
    QVector<double>x;
    QVector<double>y;
    qint8 header[288];
};
```

My tried normal c++ `Datapackage` class

```
class Datapackage
{
public:
    Datapackage( std::vector<char> datas , int start );
    std::vector<double> getX() const;
    std::vector<double> getY() const;

private:
    std::vector<char> intensity;
    std::vector<double> x;
    std::vector<double> y;
   int8_t header[288];

};
```

My results are absurd. I am doing the wrong conversion.
Could you suggest a good way. The above class is not a complete code. I removed some data not to make the code too long.

Comment: Are you trying to change all instances of QByteArrays to vectors in your code? or do you want to convert the values and then do your operations on vectors/chars?

Comment: please expand on "absurd"

Comment: Maybe you should use char* QByteArray::data() method? Normal equivalent is std::string or std::wstring, based on character set you used.

Comment: @Andy Newman : The absurd results are as . I get the result with QT as x = 0.0941 which is the correct . while with my conversion with normal c++ code I get the result as x = -18.493 and sometimes pecuiliar symobol as smiley and arrows.

Comment: @Launa : Give us code sample. And right spelling for library is Qt, QT - Quick Time

Comment: @Olivier Poulin: I want to change all instance of QByteArrays to suitable c++ data. Changing QString to std::string , and other wont give an incorrect result. But the above two conversion is generating an error.

Comment: We need a code example.  You are talking about an array but then telling me about a float?  What line of code do you execute, what output do you expect, and what do you get instead?

Comment: **You've put the cart in front of your horse.** You assume, without any ground for it, that `QByteArray` is your problem. Most likely it isn't, you're doing something wrong, and we won't know until you show us the code.

Comment: I tried to submit a code in the comment . It's not allowing due to character limit .

Comment: Edit the code into your question, adding code to comments makes it unreadable.

Comment: The code you're giving us right now looks fine, can you give us more?

Comment: You're looking for [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21216034/1329652), I think, and I also think that this is really a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21208733/1329652). Your problem is that of storing data structures in a file or some other generic stream-of-bytes.

Comment: @Kuba Ober :) not. I just want to transfer the code in Qt to normal c++ code. I am doing a hit and trial . Other conversion as Qstring to std::string. Qvector to std::vector works fine. I tried as you said a try to wchar_t for QChar. But found wchar_t is of size of 2 bytes and QChar of 1. I am only having problem at conversion with QbyteArray and QChar . Looking the Qt documentation I tried to replace them by std::vector<char> and char .. though a wrong conversion.

Comment: @Launa But what are you doing with that data? And *what code* does show bad results? And how can intensity be stored as a vector of chars?! Remember: the problem isn't in your data structure, it is *elsewhere*, where you actually try to use that data, or do I/O with it (file, network, etc.).

Comment: @Kuba Ober: The intensity is cast to double afterwards.  As you said I will check the other parts again and find the errors.

Comment: @Launa I have no idea what would make someone "cast" a `QChar` (an opaque class) to a double. That's just ridiculous. Never mind that a `QChar` is usually smaller than a double, so you're casting junk - unless you meant casting `QChar`'s *value*. Even then, the use of `QChar` is pure nonsense unless you're not telling us something...

Comment: @Kuba Ober My apology the intensity is cast to int8_t afterwards not to double .
I did the following coversion is it correct ?

    QDataStream ds(datas.right(datas.size()-start));
    ds.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian); 

    std::stringstream ds( std::string (datas.rbegin() , datas.rend() - 1) ); // tried normal c++ conversion of above 2 lines

Answer (score 4):

`QChar` is not `char`.

`QByteArray` is not `std::vector<char>`.

A `QChar` is more like `wchar_t`, although it is a class and offers more functionality than merely storing characters. Don't forget that a `QChar` stores a UTF-16 *code unit*. Some Unicode *code points* are stored as two UTF-16 code units (called a surrogate pair). So you should never assume that one `QChar` represents a complete code point. Similarly, you should never assume that one code point represents a character. Some characters are represented by multiple code points. In general:

`number of printable characters <= number of code points <= number of code units (QChars)`

A `QByteArray` offers functionality beyond that of `std::vector`, i.e. usable with `QDataStream` etc.

> I have a previous code written in QT. The output generated is very slow.

Your problem is that you're not showing us any of that code, and you're presupposing a solution without understanding what the problem is. You've already decided that `std::vector` will be a solution, but you have really *no idea* where the problem is.

We'll need to see a [minimal](http://www.sscce.org) example that reproduces the problem, and **only then** can one decide whether `QByteArray` itself is the culprit, or (more likely) the incorrect way that you've designed your solution.

Comment: I have stated that I am doing the wrong conversion. QChar is obviously not a char. I assumed char could replace it by somemeans. Watching the output of my code. I know that it is not a suitable conversion. QByteArray has a lot of features as seen in the Qt documentation. It was just a try , a wrong try. I couldn't show the minimal example since the code is too long.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to change all instances of `QByteArray`s into `std::vector`s and `QChar`s into chars in your code, then you're going to have to give us some errors that you're getting for us to help you.

However, if you want to do a conversion to vectors/chars and then do your computations on those, then you can use these:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> newVector(
oldByteArray.begin(), oldByteArray.end());
```

and

```
myChar = oldQChar.toAscii();
or
myChar = oldQChar.toLatin1();
```